# Laravel 9 sail php migrate returns MySQL 2002 error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sail

I have another MySQL 5.7 container. I wanted the MySQL 8 that comes with Laravel 9 to use port 3308 instead of 3306 so I have this **.env**:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:yiU0J8TWntz0c20bwsC1D/LqyZ6Hc+/BUczEiGYfPxM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=store
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6380

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700
```

and **docker-compose.yml**:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '8088:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - mailhog
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '3308:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            #MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '6380:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/meili_data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

However, trying `./vendor/bin/sail php artisan migrate` leads to MySQL error 2002:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from
> information_schema.tables where table_schema = store and table_name =
> migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

What is the issue there and how could I solve it.

#### Update (1)

In **.env** I changed The DB_HOST and DB_PORT to:

```
DB_HOST=store-mysql-1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=store
DB_USERNAME=sail
```

Where `store-mysql-1` is the name of MySQL8 container of Laravel.
I got the following Error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sail'@'**172.20.0.7**'
> (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
> where table_schema = store and table_name = migrations and table_type
> = 'BASE TABLE')

The most important notice here, the IP `172.20.0.7` **is not** the IP of the container named `store-mysql-1 which I could determine it using the command:

`docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' store-mysql-1` and it returns: `172.20.0.2`

#### Update (2)

Using the command:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/sail mysql
```

returns the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sail'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)

#### Update (3) *the solution*

Using the following command I removed the images and then run `sail up` again, everything is solved with the same settings of of both **.env** and **docker-compose.yml** files except, to set a password in **.env** `DB_PASSWORD=pwd123+` and uncomment `#MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'` in **docker-compose.yml**:

```
./vendor/bin/sail down --rmi all -v
```

**However**, I saw this solution somewhere in this community but I have no idea why does it solve the issue and what is the root cause of it?

Answer (score 1):

The `.env` must be using the docker composer container name, that is how the container knows where to point to (host), so `DB_HOST` must be `mysql` literally, because that is the one you want (MySQL 8).

And the `DB_PORT` must be equal to the internal port `3306`. You are exposing `3308` to outside connections, but internally is still using `3306`.

Then, whatever command you execute, it must be run inside the PHP container, I think `sail` already does this for you, but if you want to manually go inside the PHP container just do `docker compose exec laravel.test bash`

Comment: Please, checkout the **Update (1)**.

Comment: @SaidbakR can you also update the docker compose file? I do not see any `store-mysql-1` in there

Comment: I updated the docker composer, but the same. The second IP is for the `store-laravel.test-1` container and I think it has MySQL client inside it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, you should not care at all about the IP, just the container name, that is why I am asking you to update the question with the new docker compose file so I can see what image you are using and all of that as there seems to be something missing on that container declaration

Comment: The docker-compose file is still the same as regarded in the question. Changes have been done on the .env only.

Comment: You do not have any `store-mysql-1` container defined in your docker compose file... If it is outside the file network, you must use the same network...

Comment: No, the docker container named `store-mysql-1` is always there. However, take a look at the **Update (3)** that solves the issue, but I don't know why!

Comment: Again, in your docker compose there is no `store-mysql-1` (at least in your question), second: you have uncommented `MYSQL_PASSWORD` because you don't need a password... see that you have `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1`, so the `MYSQL_USER` does not require a password (`DB_PASSWORD=` literally when trying to connect)...